# RDD get type and index of each element

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, mapper

I am looking for ways to get type and index of each element in Java.  For instance, suppose there is an RDD

```
['0,1,hi,1.0', '2,3,String,String2', '1.0,2.0,3,String']
```

Then I want

```
[(0, int),(1, int),(2, String),(3, Double),(0, int) ........]
```

So that I can reduce by keys and see the data types for each column. I achieved it in python, but not sure about how to do this in Java. Is there any way to do this? Here is how I did it in python

```
def infer_type(partition):
for row in partition:
    value = ""
    idx = 0
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[0] == self.prop.comment:
            break
        if row[i] == self.prop.delimiter or i == (len(row) - 1):
            if i == len(row) - 1:
                value += str(row[i])
            if bool(value.strip()) == False:
                yield (idx, 'None')
            elif int_regex_match.match(value):
                yield (idx, 'int')
            elif float_regex_match.match(value):
                yield (idx, 'float')
            else:
                if date_regex_match.match(value):
                    yield (idx, 'date')
                else:
                    yield (idx, 'str')
                idx += 1
                value = ""
        else:
            value += str(row[i])
    rdd = rdd.mapPartitions(infer_type).map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1]), 1)).reduceByKey(add).map(
    lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0][1], x[1])))
```

EDIT : This is what I got upto now. However, I can't get iterator of tuple.

```
PairFlatMapFunction map = new PairFlatMapFunction<Iterator<String>, Integer, String>(){

        @Override
        public Iterator<Tuple2<Integer, String>> call(Iterator<String> iterator) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                String[] row = iterator.next().split(",");
                for(int j = 0; j<row.length;j++) {
                    if(row[j].matches(int_regex)) {
                        Tuple2<Integer, String> result =new Tuple2(j, "int");
                        // return iterator of result..?
                    }else if(row[j].matches(float_regex)) {
                        Tuple2<Integer, String> result =new Tuple2(j, "float");
                        // return iterator of result..?
                    }else if(row[j].matches(date_regex_match)) {
                        Tuple2<Integer, String> result =new Tuple2(j, "date");
                        // return iterator of result..?
                    }else {
                        Tuple2<Integer, String> result =new Tuple2(j, "str");
                        // return iterator of result..?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 };
JavaPairRDD pair_rdd = rdd.mapPartitionsToPair(map, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the need you express, I cannot see why you use `mapPartition` instead of simply `map`. Also another mistake here is that you should be using `flatMapToPair` instead of `mapToPair`.

To achieve what you want, your `flatmap` function needs to map a string (e.g. `"0,1,hi,1.0"`) to an iterator of tuples. To do that, you can simply create an `ArrayList` of the results you compute :

```
@Override
public Iterator<Tuple2<Integer, String>> call(String row) throws Exception {
    String[] split_row = row.split(",");
    //create list
    List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> result = new ArrayList<>()
    for(int j = 0; j<split_row.length;j++) {
        if(split_row[j].matches(int_regex)) {
            result.add(new Tuple2(j, "int"));
        } //else ...
    }
    //return the iterator
    return result.iterator();
}
```

In case you actually need to use mapPartition, you can apply the same logic to your function.

Comment: I wanted to use mapPartition since I have read mapPartition is better in perofmance. Isn't that so?

Comment: String[] row = iterator.next().split(","); --> where is iterator coming from?

Comment: I copy pasted the code from the question and forgot to modify that part. I edited my answer. Thanks ;-)

Comment: In case you want to use mapPartition, take an iterator as an input and wrap my function inside a for loop that iterates over all its rows ;-)